# Probability of hitting a four in cricket

Tags: probability, statistics, data-analysis

Based on historical data, I calculated the probability of hitting a four (a type of shot) in cricket in one ball to be 0.114 (11.4%) [total number of fours / total number of balls]. In this case, how would I calculate the probability of a certain player hitting F fours in B balls?

I tried simply multiplying the probability per ball by the number of balls, but this at times gives results far greater than 1 (when the number of fours is more than expected). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the results of each ball is independent, what you want is described by the [**binomial distribution**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). If $p$ is the probability of a four on a given ball (note $p=0.114$ for you), then the probability of getting exactly $F$ fours in $B$ balls is $$\binom{B}{F}p^F (1-p)^{B-F}.$$

Here, $\binom{B}{F}$ is a [**binomial coefficient**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), equal to $\frac{B(B-1)(B-2)\ldots (B-F+1)}{F!}$.